# Arbitrary Number of Arguments

Tags: java, parameters, heap-memory

I try to write a function that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments such as:

```
public static void closeAllIfApproriate( final AutoCloseable... array ) throws SpecialException
{
    
    try {
        
        if( array == null)
            return;
        
        for( AutoCloseable value: array )
        {
            close(value);
        }
        
    } catch (SpecialExceptionhata) {

        throw hata;

    }
    
}


public static void close (final AutoCloseable value ) throws SpecialException
{           
    // Even if nothing happened, something definitely happened.

    if(value != null)
        value.close();  
    
}
```

The function *closeAllIfApproriate* shall work properly for the sake of the other projects that depend upon it.

We know that *array* above will cause a heap allocation for an instance of this class. When I take a look at the way Google Guava is implemented, I have seen such sort of things:

[[1]](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java)

```
 /**
   * Returns an immutable list containing the given elements, in order.
   *
   * @throws NullPointerException if any element is null
   */
  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(
      E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10, E e11) {
    return construct(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, e11);
  }

  // These go up to eleven. After that, you just get the varargs form, and
  // whatever warnings might come along with it. :(

  /**
   * Returns an immutable list containing the given elements, in order.
   *
   * <p>The array {@code others} must not be longer than {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE - 12}.
   *
   * @throws NullPointerException if any element is null
   * @since 3.0 (source-compatible since 2.0)
   */
  @SafeVarargs // For Eclipse. For internal javac we have disabled this pointless type of warning.
  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(
      E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10, E e11, E e12, E... others) {
    checkArgument(
        others.length <= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 12, "the total number of elements must fit in an int");
    Object[] array = new Object[12 + others.length];
    array[0] = e1;
    array[1] = e2;
    array[2] = e3;
    array[3] = e4;
    array[4] = e5;
    array[5] = e6;
    array[6] = e7;
    array[7] = e8;
    array[8] = e9;
    array[9] = e10;
    array[10] = e11;
    array[11] = e12;
    System.arraycopy(others, 0, array, 12, others.length);
    return construct(array);
  }
```

As you can see, Google engineers prefer to write *of* function for each number of parameters, rather than writing a single function such as:

```
 public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of( E... parameters ) {
    return construct(parameters);
  }
```

Does the function above cause problems in the heap? What would be the intention of Google developers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google's intentions and practices aren't really that great or clear most of the time; more often than not they prefer doing things in a way that's prohibited to regular non-google developers.

Comment: So Guava's reason was that `@SafeVarargs` didn't exist yet, but Java 9's reason was performance.